# The following message was thrown building GetX<LogoPickerController>(controller: Instance of 'LogoPickerController', tag: null, has builder, dirty

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using Getx. But i amfacing this issue:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
> ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
> following message was thrown building
> GetX(controller: Instance of
> 'LogoPickerController', tag: null, has builder, dirty, state:
> GetXState#ec9a5(controller: Instance of
> 'LogoPickerController')):
> [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.
> You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
> If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into      GetX/Obx
> or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update
> (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
> If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.

**The Code Is:**

```
 Center(
            child: GetX<LogoPickerController>(
                init: LogoPickerController(),
                builder: (controller) {
                  if (controller.image?.value != null) {
                    return CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      child: ClipOval(
                          child: Image.file(
                        controller.image?.value ?? File(""),
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      )),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const EntityLogoPickerWidget();
                  }
                }),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetX and Obx are preferred to be used when we are using reactive variables.

Try replacing `GetX` with `GetBuilder`. That is

```
Center(
            child: GetBuilder<LogoPickerController>(
                init: LogoPickerController(),
                initState: (_) {},  //NOT NEEDED
                builder: (controller) {
                  if (controller.image?.value != null) {
                    return CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      child: ClipOval(
                          child: Image.file(
                        controller.image?.value ?? File(""),
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      )),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const EntityLogoPickerWidget();
                  }
                }),
          ),
```

Comment: but this widget does not rebuild the UI when the user pick an image . 
if i pick an image no change happen, when i make hot reload the image appears @Krish Bhanushali

Comment: @winter can you share your controller.

Comment: i changed the controller's value to be not observable, thanks your answer was helpful.